# Playing back a CMSampleBuffer

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, cmsamplebuffer

I'm trying to create an application that streams video and audio to an other computer.

On the "server" side, I'm able to capture (using `AVCaptureSession`) video and audio, to preview them and to send them over the network using the delegate and reconstruct everything back on the other side.

On "client" side I've then a `CMSampleBuffer` that contains audio and video and I don't find the way to play it back. I've checked `AVPlayer` and `AVCaptureSession`, but I don't understand the mechanism with a `CMSampleBuffer` for input.

Any ideas, links? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer.